# Rest API returns No_Access error to System Admin for userinfo call

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

We have used oAuth in our manage package. This package have oAuth flow and it works fine for all client except one.

When we call /services/oauth2/userinfo it returns

> 404 (not found) — No_Access   User lacks proper access to organization
>   or information

We are using **system admin** user to connect and other API calls are working fine.

Any one have come across this issue?

The Help page also list this error but the cause of it. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_using_userinfo_endpoint.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, It turns out that the issue was due to generic URL **https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo**

When we tried with using **https://CS2.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo** it worked just fine.

So, the point is we should always use the SERVER URL returned in login response to login API.